# How can i configure the model of ActiveForm in twig

Tags: yii2, twig, yii2-basic-app

I'm creating a basic login form by following this link [Yii2 twig guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-twig/doc/guide/2.0/en/layouts-and-widgets).

The problem is that the "model" part of 
`"{{ form.field(model, 'username') | raw }}"` is empty. How can I pass the LoginForm model (or any model) to my twig layout?
I've tried to create a global reference to the `LoginForm` model in my config file but that does not work either.

This is the form code is use in my twig template.

```
{{ use('yii/widgets/ActiveForm') }}
{% set form = active_form_begin({
    'id' : 'login-form',
    'options' : {'class' : 'form-horizontal'},
}) %}
    {{ form.field(model, 'username') | raw }}
    {{ form.field(model, 'password').passwordInput() | raw }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
{{ active_form_end() }}
```